# Setting the Datasource for ComboBoxes in cels in Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, datagridview, combobox, datasource

I've got a gridview where the columns binds its data to the `Datagrid.DataContext` in `Page_Loaded`:

```
private void Shema_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GridName.DataContext = AllPdiLines;
}
```

I want a grid where one of the cells in every line contains a combobox with selectable values which then binds to the datagrid datasource when selected. Should be easy, but a can't bind the itemscollection for the combobox.

The xaml looks like this:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="GridName" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}"                 
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
SelectionMode="Single"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
Margin="4">
<data:DataGrid.Columns>
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First name">
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="LastName" CanUserSort="True">
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country">
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cbxQ" IsEnabled="True"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Country,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Countries, Source={StaticResource CountryDataSource}}" 
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CountryListTemplate}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>                              
</data:DataGrid.Columns>
```

So, I set the DataContext for the DataGrid and the two first columns binds nicely, but how can I set the datasource for selectable values in the ComboBox in every row.

regards
Øyvind

Comment: What version of SL are you using?

Comment: What is the data type of the Country property?

Answer (score 0):

What is CountryDataSource? You cannot use a DomainDataSource with Comboboxes for several reasons. You can use the comboboxextensions package and use the comboboxdatasource. If you bind that to your datasource in your grid definition it will work.

More details here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/06/18/combobox-sample-for-ria-services.aspx

Comment: I just realized that this is a very very old question, but leaving the answer here none-the-less.